# is @import cached in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I found this import directive in a css file I am working on at the moment:

```
@import url("adverts.css");
```

When I look at the website in Chrome, `adverts.css` gets imported fine and all the styles from this file get used just as expected. However if I look at the website in FireFox they don't!

The even odder thing is that when I rename `adverts.css` to `adverts1.css` and change the import to:

```
@import url("adverts1.css");
```

the file all of a sudden works in FireFox :D

So I am wondering if FireFox has some strange caching in place for css `@import`s?

fyi: I use FireFox 22.0

Comment: Well i would guess that you probably have an AdBlock extension installed in FireFox, that detects `adverts.css` as ad but `adverts1.css` not. Anyway you should try to avoid to use `@import`. If you have many css rules and if you want to organize them in different logical files you should think over css preprocessors instead.

Comment: omg yes that's it! thanks so much, i'd never thought of this...i have adblock plus installed in firefox and once i switched that off it worked perfectly well. please post your comment as an answer below and i will give you a green tick :)

Comment: Adblock has caused me many "huh?" moments over the years. Keep an eye out for it

Comment: It's not only annoying with filenames, but also with `class` or `id` names. I started to add AdBlock tests to my quality test pipeline, testing my paths and html agains the common rulesets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the comment the problem was the installed AdBlocker.

The change from `adverts.css` to `adverts1.css` had the result, that the file did not match a rule for ad detection anymore, and therefore was loaded then.

To avoid such problems (also with other plugins) I test my sites with the common plugins and without any plugins. In Chrome most of the problematic plugins are deactivated in private browsing. Or you can use different Profiles one for testing without plugins, one with the problematic ones and one for normal browsing.

Comment: No. All AddOns are still available in private browsing.

Comment: @byf-ferdy ok thx, i also had the time now to check this and updated the answer according to this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server configuration. Your browser does request the file but it might receive a `304 Not Modified` and so not request the file again. You can see this in Firefox using the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) extension.

my_layout.css

```
@import "test.css";
```

On first request:

```
GET my_layout.css  200 Ok
GET test.css       200 Ok
```

On second request:

```
GET my_layout.css  304 Not Modified 
GET test.css       304 Not Modified
```